# How to use chained Javascript comparison operators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the following IF statement the code is being run despite the React Context variable 'newUser' being true.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (appState.newUser!==true && myMessageCount !== null || mySentMessageCount !== null) {
        console.log("IF statement executed")
    }
},[myMessageCount, mySentMessageCount, appState.newUser])
```

It also runs if I change the first condition to 'appState.newUser===false'

As I understand it, the code in the IF statement should only run if the conditions in statement one and either of statement two or three are met. Is this correct? What am I doing wrong here, please?

Comment: The **OR** (`||`) statement is probably messing with your logic. Add some parentheses to prioritize your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third param `|| mySentMessageCount !== null` is becoming `true` and since there is `||` operator no matter how many false there is if at least one is true it will return true.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood this from MDN "The logical AND (&&) operator (logical conjunction) for a set of operands is true if and only if all of its operands are true". How did you know the third param was becoming true?